# Steps in installing ubuntu after burning iso image on disc

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

After burning iso image onto disc,what is the next step to proceed in installing ubuntu?
plz provide the steps....

Comment: Have you solved this question?

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps to install Ubuntu from CD are the same for installing any operating system from CD.

For complete step-by-step instructions on how to install Ubuntu, visit the [Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).

Furthermore you can at the [boot from CD Website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).